# Specifying a function with templates that takes and returns an arbitrary class

Tags: oop, templates, d

I'm interested in defining a function that given a class variable, generates and a new instance of the class object with a randomly selected member attribute mutated.

Context: *Consider an instance, `circle1`, of some class, `Circle`, has attributes `color` and `radius`. These attributes are assigned values of `red` and `5`, respectively. The function in question, `mutate`, must accept `circle1` as an argument, but reject non-class arguments.*

For other data types, templates provide an answer in this context. That is, templates may be used to specify generic instances of functions that can accept arguments of multiple types.

**How can a generic function that accepts (and returns) an instance of any class be defined using templates?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, if you need to restrict what a template can take, you use template constraints. e.g.

```
import std.traits : isIntegral;

auto foo(T)(T t)
    if(isIntegeral!T)
{
    ...
}
```

or

```
import std.functional : binaryFun;

auto foo(alias pred, T, U)(T t, U u)
    if(is(typeof(binaryFun!pred(t, u.bar())) == bool)
{
    ...
}
```

As long the condition can be checked at compile time, you can test pretty much anything. And it can be used for function overloading as well (e.g. [`std.algorithm.searching.find`](http://dlang.org/phobos/std_algorithm_searching.html#.find) has quite a few overloads all of which are differentiated by template constraint). The built-in [`__traits`](http://dlang.org/spec/traits.html), the eponymous templates in [`std.traits`](http://dlang.org/phobos/std_traits.html), and [`is` expressions](http://dlang.org/spec/expression.html#IsExpression) provide quite a few tools for testing stuff at compile time and then using that information in template constraints or [`static if`](http://dlang.org/spec/version.html) conditions.

If you specifically want to test whether something is a class, then use an `is` expression with `== class`. e.g.

```
auto foo(T)(T t)
    if(is(T == class))
{
    ...
}
```

In general though, you'll probably want to use more specific conditions such as `__traits(compiles, MyType result = t.foo(22))` or `is(typeof(t.foo(22)) == MyType)`. So, you could have something like

```
auto mutate(T)(T t)
    if(is(T == class) &&
       __traits(compiles, t.color = red) &&
       __traits(compiles, t.radius = 5))
{
    ...
}
```

If the condition is something that you want to reuse, then it can make sense to create an eponymous template - which is what's done in Phobos in places like [std.range.primitives](http://dlang.org/phobos/std_range_primitives.html) and  [std.range.traits](http://dlang.org/phobos/std_traits.html). For instance, to test for an input range, [`std.range.primitives.isInputRange`](http://dlang.org/phobos/std_range_primitives.html#isInputRange) looks something like

```
template isInputRange(R)
{
    enum bool isInputRange = is(typeof(
    {
        R r = R.init;     // can define a range object
        if (r.empty) {}   // can test for empty
        r.popFront();     // can invoke popFront()
        auto h = r.front; // can get the front of the range
    }));
}
```

Then code that requires an input range can use that. So, lots of functions in Phobos have stuff like

```
auto foo(R)(R range)
    if(isInputRange!R)
{
    ...
}
```

A more concrete example would be this overload of [`find`](http://dlang.org/phobos/std_algorithm_searching.html#.find):

```
InputRange find(alias pred = "a == b", InputRange, Element)
               (InputRange haystack, Element needle)
    if(isInputRange!InputRange &&
       is(typeof(binaryFun!pred(haystack.front, needle)) : bool))
{
    ...
}
```

Ali Çehreli's book, [Programming in D](http://ddili.org/ders/d.en/index.html), has several relevant chapters, including:

http://ddili.org/ders/d.en/templates.html
http://ddili.org/ders/d.en/cond_comp.html
http://ddili.org/ders/d.en/is_expr.html
http://ddili.org/ders/d.en/templates_more.html